# Ideal RAID and disk layout for a SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to configure 6 disk raid for SQL Server + OS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/165344/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-6-disk-raid-for-sql-server-os)

As a general rule what would be an ideal disk layout for a SQL server which is mainly used for a fairly read and write intensive web app?

Would the following be good?

```
Logical Disk 1 - RAID 1 - OS and SQL Server Program Files
Logical Disk 2 - RAID 10 - SQL data files
Logical Disk 3 - RAID 1 - SQL log files
Logical Disk 4 - RAID 1 - TempDB files
```

Anythign else? I have seen some configurations with a seperate disk for the windows swap file?

Also this setup would have a minimum requirement of 10 physical disks. That is a lot of disks? I'm looking at a rack of server just now and all of them have space for six disks? How do people normally accommodate the need for more disks? SAN storage?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/150049/what-would-be-the-optimal-disk-config-for-sql-server-2008-r2 or http://serverfault.com/questions/38511/ms-sql-layout-for-best-performance or http://serverfault.com/questions/77141/sql-2008-disk-layout-on-a-budget-this-is-for-database-mirroring or http://serverfault.com/questions/165344/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-6-disk-raid-for-sql-server-os

Comment: Also regarding the RAID level choices, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165383/optimal-raid-setup-for-sql-server/165444#165444 (was before ServerFault.com so it survived being asked on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

The overall layout you've given is what we use for DBs with direct-attached storage.  We're a Dell shop, so we use 15-spindle MD3000 arrays for this sort of thing.

Don't bother with a dedicated swap spindle. If you're hitting the swap hard enough to dedicate a spindle to it (hitting swap much at all, really)  something is Very Wrong.